# Sending keystroke event 'paste' to a specific application Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility, macos-carbon, cgeventtap

i am using a code to simulate a 'Paste ' to the frontmost application using carbon on MacOS. Now, i need to do that to a specific application not in frontmost. I am using this code so far with the use of PostToPsn :

```
   ProcessSerialNumber psn;
   //Using 8844 for testing purposes (safari)
   OSStatus err = GetProcessForPID(8844, &psn);

   CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
   CGEventRef cmdDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source,kVK_ANSI_V, YES);
   CGEventSetFlags(cmdDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
   CGEventRef cmdUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, kVK_ANSI_V, NO);

   if(err == noErr){

       CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, cmdDown);
       CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, cmdUp);

       CFRelease(cmdUp);
       CFRelease(cmdDown);
       CFRelease(source);

   }
```

It works using just a letter but when doing a combo with command, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I believe that in order for a paste event to work the application would need to become 'frontmost'.

Comment: Make sense, ill try that.

Comment: right, now i focus the process before doing the CGEventPost and it works